# Xamarin.Forms PCL assemly issue

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a multi-platform PCL App with Xamarin.Forms using [this sqlite-pcl package](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), as show [in this sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/).

**WARNING**
The nuget site of the [PCL library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) contains a wrong link on the left, when you go to `Project Site` - it points to the [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) site... So I don't even know what the correct Sqlite-PCL link would be...

It worked just fine until this morning, when I tried to install some other packages (note that I didn't touch sqlite packages at first). All of a sudden, my app crashed at first DB access saying that

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'SQLite-net, Version=1.4.118.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Well, ok, I started searching forums, trying to find which part could be the source of the issue - just nothing helped - uninstalling and re-installing the package, rebooting, manually deleting all references to that dll I found and recompiling, re-deploying... I'm actually stuck, I tried `Fuslogvw` without succes... I am quite desperate about this - any suggestion as to how I could find the origin of the problem?

Technical details:
- VS Community 2017
- Build configuration: Debug - Any CPU - UWP on locale maching
- is there any other relevant data?

OK, after hours of searaching, and thanks to @yuri-s, I re-installed the `SQLite.Net.Async-PCL` package. I had to update some `using` clauses, but eventually, I seem to get there.

However, I am stuck with one last point: I need to create the DB connection using platform-specific assembly in this specific library - but I couldn't find what the code in the approach suggested [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23678/isqliteplatform) (last post). But I couldn't figure out what code was supposed to get into the dependency interface of each OS (`SQLite.Net.Platform` does not seem to exist in that package).

Alltogether, the SQLite-PCL packages are quite confusing - I think that the community would benefit from a clear distinction of them...!

Comment: [Sorry for the poor english] Check if these other packages have some shared dependency with your version of sqlite-net. Maybe it have updated that dependence and it messed it all.

Comment: Same thing happened as soon as I updated the NuGet packages today. Your answer cleared everything up - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be quite a lot of confusion between the different PCL versions...

I managed to get it working [following tutorial](https://mcnextpost.com/2016/05/30/xamarin-using-sqlite-net-async-in-pcl/).

Key point to remember:

1. Install [SQLite.NET.Async-PCL v3.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/3.1.1) for all projects (once via Manage NuGet packages for solution),
2. Install the  [SQLite.NET-PCL v3.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/3.1.1) for all projects (had to do it individually, via the NuGet Console) - NOTE: make sure it installs for the correct project (if not, it will complain that the package already exists),
3. For UWP, one also need to add the [Visual Studio extension for UWP](https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-uwp-3130000.vsix) and add references to it manually via `References->Add`.

So all that and it finally worked - so the mismatch was between packages of 1. and 2. (updating 1. implies one should also update individual packages in 2.)...

Hope that this will help anyone who gets confused between the SQlite packages (and, see warning in question - links to project pages on the NuGet Library pages are NOT correct!!!)

Answer (score 4):

**install sqlite-net-pcl version 1.3.3** (previous version not current)

current version 1.4.118.0 has this problem

Answer (score 2):

Filed this as an issue on [Github](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/601#event-1203690628)

Should be resolved in [1.5.166-beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.5.166-beta)

Comment: 1.5.166-beta still not fixed.

Comment: I tried  1.5.166-beta and it works for UWT but not for Android :(

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed** when I had same issues with "sqlite-net-pcl -Version 1.4.118" couldn't downgrade due to .net v4.5

upgraded to beta version **sqlite-net-pcl -Version 1.5.166-beta** and it works.